# Angular google maps click event not firing

Tags: jquery, angularjs, google-maps

I'm using [this Angular Google Maps API](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/)

The click event on the marker isn't firing, although in chrome debugger it goes through the helloWorld function on page load for each marker on the map.

Here is my first code:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="{latitude: 59.325, longitude: 18.07}"
                    zoom="8">
<ui-gmap-marker coords="{latitude: 59.325, longitude: 18.07}"
                idKey="1"
                ng-click="helloWorld()">
</ui-gmap-marker></ui-gmap-google-map>
```

And the heavily striped down directive:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app.office-map')
    .directive('infoBox', infoBox);
    infoBox.$inject = ['uiGmapGoogleMapApi', 'InfoBox', '$q'];

function infoBox(uiGmapGoogleMapApi, InfoBox, $q) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: ['^uiGmapMarker', '^uiGmapGoogleMap'],
        link: infoBoxDirective,
        replace: false,
        scope: { model: '=' }
    };

    function infoBoxDirective(scope, elem, attr) {

        $q.all({
            infoBoxInstant: uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (gmaps) {

                scope.infoOptions = {
                    content: '<div>Hello</div>',
                    alignBottom: true,
                    disableAutoPan: true,
                    pixelOffset: new gmaps.Size(10, -55),
                    maxWidth: 0,
                    zIndex: 3,
                    isHidden: false,
                    closeBoxURL: "",
                    pane: "floatPane",
                    enableEventPropagation: false
                };
                return new InfoBox(scope.infoOptions);
            })
        }).then(function () {

            scope.helloWorld = function () {
                alert('Hello World!');
            };
        });
    }
}})();
```

Don't worry about the scope.infoOptions. They are irrelevant here, but the end goal is to get up an infobox on hover.
I actually had the infobox working before I put it into this directive.

I also have these in the app module in a different file:

```
'uiGmapgoogle-maps',
'uiGmapgoogle-maps.providers'
```

As I said before we had an infobox working before we made this directive.
Sorry if it's confusing with the directive that I have striped down so much, but I didn't want to post the whole thing with a lot of irrelevant code to make it even more confusing for you.

Our main script file define the options for the map and get the data from our database to get where the markers should be placed on the map.
And that is not a directive, just an angular controller. But not even there it workes anymore.

Also, sorry I don't have a plunker or jsFiddle for you. Strangely didn't get that to work for me. But I know there are other people here that know angular much better than me and might knows why this is happening without the need of a plunker example.

Comment: Why are you waiting for a callback to define a scope function? Why don't you just define it in the scope directly, to start with?

Comment: Well, we have some other code that I didn't write there. Now I'm not the most experienced with angular so I can't remember what my college said we needed it for, but the functions to open the infobox is just before my helloWorld function in the ".then". Just didn't include it here.

Comment: From the documentation, the markers support "click", you may just use it instead of "ng-click" : http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api

Comment: Oh damn I forgot about that. So "click" worked when I put the helloWorld function in our main controller. But still doesn't work in the directive. Even if I move it to above the first return where the restrict and all is.
Also, just noticed that you only hit the breakpoint when the page is loaded and not when you actually click the marker.

Comment: Strange, so I have a breakpoint at the function in chrome and it stoped at it when I load the page as I said. But I always just pressed "resume". I now tried the "step over next function call" and I got the alert... So it actually does work in some way, but not as a click event.